# What are the main advantages in using promises in scheme?

Tags: scheme

Pragmatically, what are the main advantages of using promises? Can you show me some examples of real-life useful usage of promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme a promise is just a value that has a task that is not necessarily done yet and if you never use the value it will never be calculated. In short it is a way to do lazy evaluation in the otherwise eager Scheme. A typical way is to do computations on streams instead of lists.

With lists you can use higher order functions so that you can have a list, then filter it for values you are interested in, then transform these values and perhaps at some point you have enough to produce the value you needed. This is nice since you can abstract each step so that you can make logic that only does one step and compose steps to make the whole program, but in this scenario the first step needs to finish in full before the next step can handle the result of the first while it might be that if you are searching for the first prime number between 0 and 1000 having iterated over all the numbers in each step might not be so effective. Here is where streams comes in.

With streams the code looks the same, but the intermediate result is made by need. A stream is a pair where the parts are promises so that the code that would otherwise make a pair is delayed until the values are used. Every step just produces enough data for the next step and thus should it be enough for the first step to iterate just 20% of the elements for the last step to have computed the final result the 80% rest will never ever be processed in any of the steps. With such a structure the initial stream can also be infinite, like all the numbers from 0 increased by 1.

There are penalties involved using streams. Imagine you make an algorithm that would visit all the elements anyway. Then a stream version of an algorithm would be slower since the promises that are created and the forcing gives th eprogram overhead compared with doing the computation without laziness.

You might be interested in seeing [Hal Abelson explaining streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2Qt9uxhNSM&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46&index=11) and their pros and cons.

There are other alternatives to streams an lazy evaluation. One is [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)). Here you can also make composable procedures that takes a generator and produces a generator. The iteration will be by need like with streams.

Another alternative would be [transducers](https://youtu.be/6mTbuzafcII). This is also composable and iterates like streams and generators, but unlike generators initial data cannot be an infinite sequence like with streams and generators unless the underlying structure supports it.

*The advantages of using promises or any other technique in this answer is not scheme specific. They are true for all eager programming languages!*